# How to add a key value as a main data object to a existing json query in ansible?

Tags: json, ansible, ansible-filter

I query some information from cisco apic controller and I cutout the necessary information using `json_query`  filter as follows:

```
set_fact: 
  my_nodes: "{{ my_nodes| json_query('current[*].fabricNodeIdentP.attributes.{node_name: name, node_id: nodeId, pod_id:podId}') }}"
```

Result is the following JSON formatted data:

```
"my_nodes": [
            {
                "node_id": "1", 
                "node_name": "node01", 
                "pod_id": "1"
            }, 
            {
                "node_id": "2", 
                "node_name": "node02", 
                "pod_id": "1"
            }, 
            {
                "node_id": "3", 
                "node_name": "node03", 
                "pod_id": "1"
            }
        ]
```

What I want to have/achieve is, to have `node_name` as the main data object which should look like this:

```
{
    "node01":
    {
        
           "node_id": "1", 
           "pod_id": "1"
        
    },
    "node02":
    { 
        
           "node_id": "2", 
           "pod_id": "1"
    },    
    "node03":
    {
        
           "node_id": "3", 
           "pod_id": "1"
        
    }
}
```

I've tried to use the `combine` filter but I could only add a new key:value pair with it. Is there any way to achieve thin in ansible?

Comment: Do you really need a list of dictionaries?  Wouldn't a simple dictionary be better?

Comment: You are right that was a copy/paste there is no need to put dicts into a list. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the declarations as [appropriate](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

```yaml
my_nodes_keys: "{{ my_nodes|map(attribute='node_name')|list }}"
my_nodes_dict: "{{ dict(my_nodes_keys|zip(my_nodes)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_nodes_dict:
    node01:
      node_id: '1'
      node_name: node01
      pod_id: '1'
    node02:
      node_id: '2'
      node_name: node02
      pod_id: '1'
    node03:
      node_id: '3'
      node_name: node03
      pod_id: '1'
```

---

Q: ***"If I put them under the same set_fact ansible gives an error that my_nodes_keys is not defined."***

A: Unfortunately, it's not possible to 're-use' variables in *set_fact*. For example,

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        var1: a
        var2: "{{ var1 }}"
```

fails with the error:

> The error was: 'var1' is undefined.

This means *var2* is not able to use *var1* declared in *set_fact*. There is an easy solution if you need var1 to declare var2 only. Put the declaration of *var1* into task's *vars*. The task below works as expected

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        var2: "{{ var1 }}"
      vars:
        var1: a
```

In your case, if you don't need the keys later in the playbook, put the declaration into task's *vars*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_nodes_dict: "{{ dict(my_nodes_keys|zip(my_nodes)) }}"
      vars:
        my_nodes_keys: "{{ my_nodes|map(attribute='node_name')|list }}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @VladimirBotka it worked but I had to put them into two separate tasks because if I put them under the same ```set_fact``` ansible gives an error that ```my_nodes_keys``` is not defined. Do you also mean to put it so in your answer or do I have missed something?

Comment: I added the explanation of how to deal with the *set_fact* problem. But, you can put the declarations also into the playbook's *vars* or role's *defaults* depending on your code structure.